# How to use bracketed-paste-mode in Vim/Neovim when pasting a register in insert mode?

Tags: vim, neovim

When inserting code from a register in insert mode with Vim/Neovim it will not automatically use [xterm-bracketed-paste](https://vimhelp.org/term.txt.html#xterm-bracketed-paste)(Vim) / [bracketed-paste-mode](https://neovim.io/doc/user/provider.html#provider-paste)(Neovim).

For example if I have `y`anked this function in a `demo.js` file:

```js
function x() {
  // comment
  alert("hey");
}
```

and then paste it in insert mode with `i<c-r>"` it will be messed up:

```js
function x() {
    // comment
  //   alert("hey");
  //   }
//
```

Whereas pasting the same snippet from the system clipboard (i.e. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) in insert mode works fine due to the bracketed paste feature.

I know that I can use `:set paste` before pasting. But then I either have to leave insert mode or - when mapped to a key - press a key to enable paste mode.

Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Why do you paste it in insert mode? is the original file also opened in Vim? Why don't you simplify your life with a clipboard-enabled Vim?

Comment: Why not? I think `<c-r>` is there for a reason. If I'm already in insert mode and edit a file and then want to paste a snippet I have in the system clipboard why should I leave insert mode? So far I've used ctrl + shift + v but that's so awkward to type so I would prefer `<c-r>+`. But it behaves differently due to the missing bracketed paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already said, `i_CTRL-R` inserts text as if typed. However, there are various other related keybinds that accomplish what you want:

`i_CTRL-R_CTRL-O` inserts text without auto-indentation and other format options. However, if you're pasting code, you will often want to adjust the indentation to the current level. `i_CTRL-R_CTRL-P` will automatically re-indent text as it is pasted in.

More details can be found in Vim help pages at `:help i_ctrl-r`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Not sure how I could miss that as I surely read the help for `i_CTRL-R` a couple of times while the information is only two paragraphs below under `:h i_CTRL-R_CTRL-O`.

Answer (score 0):

`:h <c-r>` does state the following:

> The text is inserted as if you typed it, but mappings and abbreviations
> are not used.

So, it does not trigger any paste commands or callbacks or anything. It is just an automated way to type in text.

The answer to problems like this is always the same: Leave insert mode.
Vim is mode based, that is the fundament of the power of vim. Insert mode is not specialized to paste stuff (although I love `<c-r>`). There is a lot of stuff you can't to in insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following mapping to paste the system clipboard in insert mode. So far it seems to do what I want.

```
inoremap <c-p> <c-o>:set paste<cr><c-r>+<c-o>:set nopaste<cr>
```